# Javascript and Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm learning on creating a website using Ruby on Rails (RoR). I had an HTML template that I created when I worked with JSP 2 years ago, and now I want to reuse it in my RoR website. This is HTML file

```
<body>

<div id="container">

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Livingroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Bedroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mattress</a></li>
        <li id="selected"><a href="#">Bathroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kitchen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Office</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SearchBar</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Nav.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nav').spasticNav();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript file jquery.Nav.js

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.spasticNav = function(options) {

        options = $.extend({
            overlap : 20,
            speed : 500,
            reset : 1500,
            color : '#0b2b61',
            easing : 'easeOutExpo'
        }, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var nav = $(this),
                currentPageItem = $('#selected', nav),
                blob,
                reset;

            $('<li id="blob"></li>').css({
                width : currentPageItem.outerWidth(),
                height : currentPageItem.outerHeight() + options.overlap,
                left : currentPageItem.position().left,
                top : currentPageItem.position().top - options.overlap / 2,
                backgroundColor : options.color
            }).appendTo(this);

            blob = $('#blob', nav);

            $('li:not(#blob)', nav).hover(function() {
                // mouse over
                clearTimeout(reset);
                blob.animate(
                    {
                        left : $(this).position().left,
                        width : $(this).width()
                    },
                    {
                        duration : options.speed,
                        easing : options.easing,
                        queue : false
                    }
                );
            }, function() {
                // mouse out    
                reset = setTimeout(function() {
                    blob.animate({
                        width : currentPageItem.outerWidth(),
                        left : currentPageItem.position().left
                    }, options.speed)
                }, options.reset);
            });
        }); // end each
    };
})(jQuery);
```

In the application.html.erb of RoR project, I include the js file like this

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Nav.js" %>
```

However, my homepage doesn't work even though I put the $('#nav').spasticNav(); inside the body tag of RoR project

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <%=  render 'layouts/header'%>

          <%=yield%>

      <%=  render 'layouts/footer'%>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nav').spasticNav();
</script>

</body>
```

Is there anyway to embed the $('#nav').spasticNav() into the js file. I tried many ways but it still doesn't work. Thanks a lot.

EDIT:  I saw some examples online that they embed the function into js file like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /*---------------------------------
        MENU Dropdowns
    -----------------------------------*/
    $('ul.menu').each(function(){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `$('#nav').spasticNav();` into a `$(document).ready` function so that it is executed when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav').spasticNav();
  });
</script>
```

Also make sure that you have a `#nav` element on the page. I couldn't tell from your html layout if you had it or not.

Comment: It still doesn't work. For the html layout, I just copy and paste the same statements between <div id="container"></div> tag. I saw some examples online they embed the function inside the js file. I update my post to show that.

Comment: Can you help me please? I've spent 5 hours on this :(

Comment: Are there any console errors when you load the page and are you sure that the `jquery.Nav.js` file is getting loaded? Try putting a simple `alert` or `console.log` into the jquery file to see if it fires properly when the page loads.

Comment: I test with `alert` and the js gets loaded. Is there anyway to not using jQuery.prototype (my teammate created the js file, not me)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you sure the nav code works? If it is included and the element exists, I'm not sure what else could be wrong...

Comment: Yes, it works. Check it out, it's a cool menu navigation `https://www.dropbox.com/s/qq7dz42a5dh88za/MenuNav.zip` But I cannot make it work in RoR. I think I give up here :(

Comment: It works fine for me if I include jQuery before your custom javascript and also include the `$(document).ready` function at the bottom of the page. Do you have your whole application hosted on GitHub or somewhere so I could take a look, or would that not be possible?

Comment: The whole application is hosted on SVN, and I don't want to bother you too much. Well if you can send me the code how you include jQuery and $(document).ready, that would be great. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have posted my solution as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jvperrin/7b094aa2ec6c29b3ad96). Hopefully it works for you.